# Maximum number of juniors on a football team

Tags: word-problem

For a certain football game the coach wants to start one sophomore and at least twice
as many seniors as sophomores and juniors combined. What is the maximum 
number of juniors he can start? Players needed to start a game is at most 11....
Answer is 2 junior players... but I can't figure out how?

I tried using:

```
     x = juniors, and 
2(x+1) = juniors & sophomores combined,
with 1 sophomore to start with,
```

but when i solved it with equating it like:

```
juniors + seniors + sophomores = 11
```

like

```
x + 2(x+1) + 1 = 11
```

I got answer `x = 8/3`, which was not correct.

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you.

Comment: its not my home work, i was preparing for sat test, and refreshing my pre-algebra and algebra 1 and 2 concepts...... i tried using x = juniors, and 2(x+1) = juniors & sophomores combined, with 1 sophomore to start with, i but when i solved it with equating it like juniors + seniors + sophomores = 11 like x + 2(x+1) + 1 = 11 i got answer x = 8 / 3, which was not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraints are
$$o+s+j\le 11\\
s=1\\
o \ge 2(s+j)$$
Where $o$ are seniors, $s$ sophomores and $j$ juniors starting. Now if $j\ge3$, $o \ge 2\cdot(3+1) = 8$ so
$o+s+j\ge12 > 11$ wich is impossible. If $j=2$, $o \ge 6$ wich is okay because $6+1+2 = 9 \le 11$. He'd send $2$ juniors, $1$ sophomore and $8$ seniors.

Comment: can it be solved without inequalities?

Comment: @Zainulabidin No. The text states inequalities in word form. There is no direct way around this.

Comment: okay. thanks a lot!